# Know if mysql has done its job

Tags: mysql

I started a mysql dump from the terminal. I am on Linux.

```
mysqldump -u foto_admin -p foto_fotografare > /home/foto/foto_sql_back.sql
```

It asked me to add a password.
I did it and the mysql dump started.
Now the terminal is stuck on there. It does not show any process.
It just where I left it on the password request.
When I look into the FTP I see the sql file and I see refreshing the FTP that no more data is added. So it looks like it is done.
But how can I be sure it did what is supposed to do?

When I run: `mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`
No processes are shown. So I must assume that the dump went ok?

Comment: what does an `ps auxf` say about the mysqldump process? Is it still visible and does it show any activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the value of `$?` when mysqldump exits. A 0 indicates success and anything else indicates an error of some description - this is the general rule for most console applications. The mysql utilities are usually very good at providing useful error messages too.

```
mysqldump ...
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Mysqdump failed - see extended error information above"
else
    echo "Mysqldump successful"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth checking the status of all your tables to see if any need to be repaired.

You could always execute the dump, then strace the PID of the dump from another session to see if data is still passing through when your original session freezes.